# No sliding (gesture typing) feature in Google Keyboard for Ukrainian language

Tags: keyboard, languages

I can't type words via "sliding through letters" in Google Keyboard when Ukrainian language is chosen.

Is it OK? What may be the reason? No "sliding" support specifically for Ukrainian language?

I have Moto G with Android KitKat.
I tried on both 2.0... and 3.0... versions of Google Keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

You can now download the latest version of Google keyboard (with sliding support) from the Google play store.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin